# Retain an old Frame using ARCore in Android

Tags: android, arcore

After watching [watching this video of AR remote support for HoloLens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFhpAe10qnk) I decided to try to do something similar but with Android and ARCore. The things was going fine until I try to do a feature shown at 2:01 which is basically getting a "screenshot" of a specific moment, draw or insert objects on it and then convert it in AR Models.

I tried to retain an instance of the [Frame](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame) however later when I try to simulate a [HitTest](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame#hitTest(android.view.MotionEvent)) I receive the following message:

```
FrameHitTest invoked on old frame, the previous state of the system is no longer available. Returning empty list.
```

So my question is: is there another approach I can try to simulate a later HitTest or it's not possible using ARCore for now?

Answer (score 2):

...

Hi Pedro,

Have you already tried to put an anchor on the center of the frame when the remote user save the photo and store it's reference somewhere?

With that anchor you can try to generate the content remotely and then send the relative coordinates and the models to client phone with an Anchor ID. 
After receiving the data the phone add the augmented content according to the anchor it refers using the previously ID.
You could also add other useful information for you (e.g. camera distance from plane in that specific frame, ...)

Hope this help or give you some hints.

Cheers.

Comment: I've been doing some tests with the anchors after seeing your answer and this seems to be the way to do it indeed :) I wish ARCore had a simpler implementation for doing that like ARKit. Maybe in a future version... Thanks very much for the idea

Comment: Hey, @TomD88 I would like to follow up on this alternative solution. How can you estimate the z-axis from the 2d screen coordinates to 3d world space? Thank you very much!

Comment: The method above assume that when a local user take a photo he send the photo with additional metadata to the remote user. The metadata contains the position and orientation of the anchor that a remote user can use to place additional content on the image received. To place the content and estimate z correctly during 2d-3d projection after the remote user tap on the image, you have to transmit the feature sparse map(or the complete sparse map) that arcore generate in that frame to allow a remote simplified reconstruction of the area where the local user is moving.

Comment: Check this link for an example of feature points https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMytXWXQ6wg